# Connect power-only usb to pcb

Tags: power-supply, power, usb

I'm trying to replace a 2 pin JST connector with a micro usb female connector to supply 5v to my circuit.

Obviously I should connect VBUS to +5v and GND to GND.

Should I connect shield to GND?

Should I do anything with the other pins (D+, D-), or just leave them not connected?

[image]

Comment: You can leave the data pins unconnected.

Answer (score 3):

If you are (ab)using USB for power only, on most computers and power supplies you can simply connect VUSB and GND. You do not need to connect shield. Keep in mind you should limit it to 500mA if you are using a PC as the source.   90% will not require enumeration.